# Log Shipping restore job failed, DBNAME is not in NORECOVERY/STANDBY mode

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

My log shipping job stopped suddenly. I'm getting this error:

```
2020-04-17 14:46:36.42  ----- START OF TRANSACTION LOG RESTORE   -----
2020-04-17 14:46:36.53  Starting transaction log restore. Secondary ID: '02d5e9cd-bd01-42d6-9a8b-9c79c2b13d01'
2020-04-17 14:46:36.55  Retrieving restore settings. Secondary ID: '02d5e9cd-bd01-42d6-9a8b-9c79c2b13d01'
2020-04-17 14:46:36.56  Retrieved common restore settings. Primary Server: 'SERVERNAME', Primary Database: 'DBNAME', Backup Destination Directory: 'D:\LOGShipping\LSSecondary', File Retention Period: 14400 minute(s)
2020-04-17 14:46:36.56  Retrieved database restore settings. Secondary Database: 'DBNAME', Restore Delay: 0, Restore All: True, Restore Mode: Standby, Disconnect Users: True, Last Restored File: D:\LOGShipping\LSSecondary\DBNAME_20200413181001.trn, Block Size: Not Specified, Buffer Count: Not Specified, Max Transfer Size: Not Specified
2020-04-17 14:46:36.64  *** Error: The restore operation cannot proceed because the secondary database 'DBNAME' is not in NORECOVERY/STANDBY mode.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2020-04-17 14:46:36.65  Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: 'DBNAME'
2020-04-17 14:46:36.69  The restore operation completed with errors. Secondary ID: '02d5e9cd-bd01-42d6-9a8b-9c79c2b13d01'
2020-04-17 14:46:36.76  ----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG RESTORE     -----

Exit Status: 1 (Error)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155891/log-shipping-restore-job-failing please check the answer here

Comment: thank you, it's work.